# How to subtract a datetime from another datetime and save to date and time?

Tags: c#, date, time

How do I subtract two DateTime values from another DateTime value and save the result to a "DateTime" and than write the subtract time in label?

```
time_spend = (time_now - time_first) //example
lbl1.Text = time_spend.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Have you... tried running the code you've written?

Comment: `time_spend` will be a `TimeSpan` and your code will work. You're probably facing issues because you probably declared `time_spend` as `DateTime`

Comment: @Magnetron Yes, I declared time_spend as DateTime. With TimeSpan works as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `someDateTime.Subtract(otherDateTime)`, this returns a `TimeSpan` which has a `TotalDays` property.

You can also `Subtract()` a `TimeSpan` and it will return a `DateTime`